# Есть ли в Qt WebKit замена loadFinished() для javascript?

Tags: c++, qt, webkit

Как можно решить ситуацию когда страница после сигнала loadFinished продолжает подгружать элементы еще 2 секунды(видимо javascript).Мне нужно спарсить данные со страницы, но этот фактор ужасно мешает.Ставить задержку 2 секунды после подгрузки страницы не хотелось бы.

Comment: Попробуйте `QWebFrame::initialLayoutCompleted()`

Answer (score 2):

Как такового сигнала о полном завершении загрузки страницы в `QtWebKit` нет. Сигнал `QWebPage::loadFinished(bool ok)` может придти несколько раз, да и все прочие сигналы похожей направленности также не гарантируют одноразовости. Оно и понятно, скрипты на странице, использующие аякс, могут начать что-нибудь подгружать с сервера в любое время и запросто поменять хоть всю html-структуру страницы.

Самым простым решением может быть такое. Цепляем свой слот к сигналу `QWebPage::loadProgress(int progress)`. Как только переменная `progress` станет равна `100`, запускаем таймер с интервалом, например, в одну секунду (лучше больше, если интернет не слишком быстрый). Если за отведённое время сигнал `QWebPage::loadProgress(int progress)` не начал срабатывать снова, то считаем, что страница полностью загружена, иначе останавливаем свой таймер и снова ждём, пока не наберётся 100% загрузки страницы.

В чём отличие от того, чтобы подключаться к `QWebPage::loadProgress(int progress)` вместо `QWebPage::loadFinished(bool ok)`? Если начнётся подгрузка данных, то первый сработает раньше, нежели чем второй, что даёт преимущество в установке таймера ожидания на меньший интервал.

Однако следует помнить о том, что на странице могут оказаться скрипты, которые не сильно балуют скоростью загрузки. Это касается в основном всяких счётчиков посетителей и т.п., которые осуществляют обращение ко внешним по отношению к текущей страницы ресурсам. В этом случае загрузка может застопориться и нередки случаи неполучения 100% весьма длительное время, иногда приводящее к равенству со словом никогда. Здесь конечно только `QWebPage::loadFinished(bool ok)`, чтобы иметь возможность считать, что хоть что-то да подгрузилось.

Разумеется, это решение не назвать не костылём, но `QtWebKit` больше не развивается и в частности эта проблема решена не будет. Можно посоветовать переходить на `QWebEngine` и, используя связку с `QWebChannel`, отслеживать загрузку страницы средствами javascript.